# Need a MySQL Query out of this diagram

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like a query that shows me the tracks that a user doesn't have in his playlist. The only parameter I'll be getting is the username of a user.

Is that possible with this diagram? If so, could you provide me with a query?

[image: Database Diagram]

I've tried a query, but not so succesfull.

```
SELECT * FROM TRACK 
INNER JOIN USER u on u.ID = TRACK.USERID
INNER JOIN Playlist p on p.TrackID = TRACK.ID
WHERE (u.ID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Playlist WHERE UserID = (SELECT ID FROM User WHERE username = 'Arjan')))
AND (TRACK.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TRACK))
```

Not sure what's missing here. Maybe I'm just thinking too complicated.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*** We're not a homework completion or code writing service.

Comment: @KenWhite Give me a minute, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get a chance to try it out actually. But your query should be something like this one --

```
Declare @UserName varchar(255)
Set @UserName = N'Arjun'

SELECT U.ID
    ,U.UserName
    ,P.ID
    ,T.Id
    ,T.TrackUrl
    ,T.CreationDate
FROM TRACK T
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.ID = T.UserID
LEFT JOIN Playlist P ON P.TrackID = T.ID
    AND P.UserID = U.ID
WHERE U.ID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM User
        WHERE UserName = @UserName
        )
    AND P.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this. I was kind of tired and couldn't figure it out on the day I posted it. Figured it out eventually, but I do appreciate that you've helped.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm a full-time free guy with no job who's using this time in learning and sometimes helping as I can.